# Need to Capture Video Stream from Camera in C# Application

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, video, streaming

I need to build an application that meets the requirements below. It can be a windows client, silverlight client or WPF client.

1. Screen will show video stream from 2 separate cameras in 2 separate windows
2. Need to have PVR type functionality that is...
   2.1 Show Live Stream
   2.2 Pause and playback previous 30 seconds of video

I'm trying to use resources I have that is C# application development however I don't have any experience with video capture.

Any help in terms of Libraries I can look at or the best way to do this.

Thanks
Cronline

Answer (score 9):

Mainly you will need to use DirectShow.

Here are useful links :

- [Camera Vision - video surveillance on C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cameraviewer.aspx)
- [DirectX.Capture Class Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx)
- [Capture Live Video from various Video Devices.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/LiveVideo.aspx)
- [C# and VB.NET Webcam Library and Sample](https://sites.google.com/site/webcamlibrarydotnet/)

Also sometimes web cams are coming with the SDK, check for it.