# Capture Picture from Web Cam in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webcam

Can anyone tell me what would best way to use capture  Picture from web cam functionality in my WPF application.I have used Microsoft Expression Encoder, but it has problem with Logitech C920 latest web cam.

Comment: Check this [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119770/need-to-capture-video-stream-from-camera-in-c-sharp-application/7119866?s=2%7C0.0000#7119866

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp) site then download and setup the necessary files.
Then, you can use this basic example too.

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
...

ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(); //create an image viewer
Capture capture = new Capture(); //create a camera captue
Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  //run this until application closed (close button click on image viewer)
   viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame(); //draw the image obtained from camera
});
viewer.ShowDialog(); //show the image viewer
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/license.html), it works flawless, free and licensed under LGPL v3 license, it also seems to work in both 32 and 64 bit.

The only drawback is that you need ~400 kb worth of dlls to get the webcam control.

Comment: This was the only package that I could use to have a nice programmatic interaction with WebCam without going insane. It's simple and works.